# How can you add 2 classname in a single div in next js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I tried to add two classname form styles but I could not add two CSS classes in a single div.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

[image]

my code is as follows:

**blog.js**

```
...
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
....
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <h2 >Recent Blogs</h2>
        <hr/>
        {blogs.map((data)=>{
          return <div key={data.slug}>
          <div className={'${styles.card} ${styles.canclick}'}>
          <Link href={`blogpost/${data.slug}`}><h3>{data.title}</h3>
          </Link>
          <em>{data.author}</em>
          </div>
          <p>{data.content.substr(0,200)}</p>
          </div>
```

**Home.module.css**

```
.canclick{ 
cursor: pointer; 
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: color 0.15s ease, border-color 0.15s ease;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: You can use `clsx` library

Comment: I think you should be using backticks here->className={'${styles.card} ${styles.canclick}'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using single quote, you need to use backtick for template string:

```
// This works
`${styles.card} ${styles.canclick}`

// This won't work
'${styles.card} ${styles.canclick}'
```

Check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp) for more context

Answer (score 0):

bro you can use class=""and className=""for same div
if you face this problem again, u can ty this snippet:
`${styles.card} ${styles.canclick}`
here the difference between your code and this code is
my code having **``**  and your code having **''**at begining and ending.
you can see this symbol in above "tab" button of your keyboard.just click that one and enjoy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add your classNames like this.

Single quote won't add your className properly, and for that you can use template literals which are used like this:

```
${styles.card} ${styles.canclick}
```